# Are "web bugs" a technique that instructs web browsers to operate the computer's microphone?

Tags: javascript

"[Web bugs](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/sp11/exams/final-solution.pdf)" [pg 7] refers to Javascript techniques that instruct web browsers to operate the computer’s microphone and locally search the audio for keywords. Would this be false? If so, why?

Comment: FYI Java and Javascript are two completely different languages.  Most browser side work is done by Javascript rather than Java so consider changing your tag and subject line reference.

Comment: Page 7 of https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/sp11/exams/final-solution.pdf - I am seeking help as I have not been taught this in my lectures. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

With the added context to the 2011 Berkeley exam answer sheet passed in your comments section the answer is indeed false.  They were looking for the Wikipedia definition of "Web Bug". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug

Answer (score 0):

There have been vulnerabilities with browser plugins such as [Flash](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/06/adobe-flash-exploit-grabs-video-and-audio-long-after-fix/), and others.

Java has a [web browser plugin](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2429779?hl=en) that might be called upon to listen to computer audio.

Native browser enhancements such as WebGL or other things might be abused to gain access to protected memory, escape the sandbox, and surreptitiously change computer settings